# Generate RTT values

Tags: java, math, networking

I'm writing a Java applet where I should be able to simulate a connection between two hosts. Hence I have to generate packet round-trip times at random.

These RTTs can go from ~0 to infinity, but are typically oscillating around some average value (i.e. an extremely large or small value is very improbable but possible). I was wondering if anyone had an idea of how I could do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're going to have to select a reasonable disribution from which to draw (pseudo) random values.  A [gamma distribuition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution) might make some sense as it seems to satisfy your requirements.  You could also use a [(left) truncated normal distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_normal_distribution).

The [Apache Commons-Math](http://commons.apache.org/math/) library for Java has code for the gamma and normal (aka Gaussian) distributions.  When using a normal distribution RNG for picking values from a truncated normal distribution, simply reject undesired draws (i.e. when you pick x <= 0, pick again).

Comment: The gamma distribution is exactly what i was looking for. I used the algorithm given on wikipedia (Generating gamma-distributed random variables) to generate the RTTs and it works fine. Thanks a lot